# Should I define a function to handle a string object or a unicode object?

Tags: python

I found that the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#tips-for-writing-unicode-aware-programs) says that `Software should only work with Unicode strings internally, converting to a particular encoding on output.`.

Does it mean that every method I define should handle the parameter as a unicode object instead of a string object? If not, when do I need to handle as a string and when do I need to handle as a unicode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what they mean.

Handle textual input from outside sources as strings, but immediately decode to unicode. Only encode back to some encoding to output it (preferably this is done by whatever function/method you call to do the output, rather than you needing to explicitly encode and then pass the encoded string somewhere).

Obviously, if you're dealing with non-text binary bytes, keep them in byte strings.

Comment: One good reason to use Python3 where strings are automatically Unicode.

Comment: @Jonathan it seems that i must try python3.